# Flatten Expression Tree

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm creating a Assembler interface which will help convert objects between different layers in my application.

E.g.

```
public interface IAssembler<TObjectSource, TObjectTarget> 
{
  IEnumerable<Expression<Func<TObjectSource, object>>> GetIncludes();

  TObjectTarget Project(TObjectSource source);
}
```

The GetIncludes the method will inform the lower level layer which parts of the source object are needed to create the target object and hence which parts then need to be loaded by that layer.

An implementation of the Book assembler could be:

```
public class BookAssembler : IAssembler<Book, BookDTO> 
{
  public BookAssembler(IAssembler<Publisher, PublisherDTO> publisherAssembler)
  {
    PublisherAssembler = publisherAssembler;
  }

  private IAssembler<Publisher, PublisherDTO> PublisherAssembler { get; }

  public IEnumerable<Expression<Func<Book, object>>> GetIncludes() {
    return Expression<Func<Book, object>>[] 
    {
      include => include.CreatedBy,
      include => include.DeletedBy,
      include => include.Publishers.Select(
        includePublisher => PublisherAssembler.GetIncludes()
      ),
      ...
    }
  }

  public BookDTO Project(Book book) {
    //Convert the book into the book DTO.
  }
}
```

The list of includes returned by the PublisherAssembler is unknown by the BookAssembler e.g. it could be 0 to N.

I need to be able to flatten the returned enumerable e.g. if PublisherAssembler.GetIncludes() returned an enumerable containing 2 items I need the output for the BookAssembler.GetIncludes() to be:

```
return Expression<Func<Book, object>>[] 
{
  include => include.CreatedBy,
  include => include.DeletedBy,
  include => include.Publishers.Select(includePublisher => includePublisher.Item1),
  include => include.Publishers.Select(includePublisher => includePublisher.Item2),
  ...
}
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Just curious why you're not using an existing mapping library instead of rolling you're own

Comment: Same concern here as mentioned by a previous comment. Check [automapper](http://automapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Getting-started.html)

Comment: I don't think you will be able to achieve this with the way you have structured the code.

Comment: Your sample code return for `BookAssembler.GetIncludes` doesn't compile.

Comment: The above is an example of something much more complex, it's to give an indication of what it I need to happen. As for using a mapping library like automapper I will for the mapping bit of it. That isn't the question however as even if I was to use a mapping library the source layer it maps from would need to be told what to include when loading the object. E.g. if there was no includes passed when loading the Book the CreatedBy, DeletedBy, Publishers properties will be null as they represent relationships and hence aren't loaded unless explicitly asked for.

Answer (score 0):

The below will do what I wanted although it will still need to be extend to handle all expression types and perform more error checking.

It essentially just walk the expression tree formatting it so it doesn't contain any Select calls with composite objects.

```
public class ExpressionFlattener 
{
    public ExpressionFlattener(MethodInfo selectMethod)
    {
        SelectMethod = selectMethod;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Flattens the specified expression.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TEntity">The type of the entity.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="expression">The expression.</param>
    /// <returns>IEnumerable&lt;Expression&lt;Func&lt;TEntity, System.Object&gt;&gt;&gt;.</returns>
    public IEnumerable<Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>> Flatten<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> expression) => Flatten(expression, new List<Expression>()).Cast<Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the select method.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The select method.</value>
    private MethodInfo SelectMethod { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Flattens the specified expression.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="expression">The expression.</param>
    /// <param name="expressions">The expressions.</param>
    /// <returns>List&lt;Expression&gt;.</returns>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentException">Invalid expression specified, the specified expression is of an unhandled node type.</exception>
    private List<Expression> Flatten(Expression expression, List<Expression> expressions)
    {
        switch (expression.NodeType)
        {
            case ExpressionType.Call: return FlattenMethodCall(expression as MethodCallExpression, expressions);
            case ExpressionType.Lambda: return FlattenLambda(expression as LambdaExpression, expressions);
            case ExpressionType.MemberAccess: expressions.Add(expression); return expressions;
            case ExpressionType.New: return FlattenNew(expression as NewExpression, expressions);
            default: throw new ArgumentException("Invalid expression specified, the specified expression is of an unhandled node type.");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Flattens the lambda expression.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="expression">The expression.</param>
    /// <param name="expressions">The expressions.</param>
    /// <returns>List&lt;Expression&lt;Func&lt;TEntity, System.Object&gt;&gt;&gt;.</returns>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentException">Invalid expression specified, the specified expression has a body with an unhandled node type.</exception>
    private List<Expression> FlattenLambda(LambdaExpression expression, List<Expression> expressions)
    {
        //Flatten the body expression.
        List<Expression> innerExpressions = Flatten(expression.Body, new List<Expression>());

        //We should never be creating a lambda expression which returns more than one property as we should
        //have flattened everything out with the call to the above. So it should be safe? to assume we're
        //inputting the same parameter type but just getting out an object.
        Type delegateType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(expression.Parameters[0].Type, typeof(object));

        //Rebuild the lambda expression for each expression returned.
        foreach (Expression innerExpression in innerExpressions)
            expressions.Add(Expression.Lambda(delegateType, innerExpression, expression.Parameters[0]));

        return expressions;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Flattens the method call expression.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="expression">The expression.</param>
    /// <param name="expressions">The expressions.</param>
    /// <param name="lambdaExpression">The lambda expression.</param>
    /// <returns>List&lt;Expression&lt;Func&lt;TEntity, System.Object&gt;&gt;&gt;.</returns>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentException">Invalid method call expression specified, the method call specified expression is to an unhandled method.</exception>
    private List<Expression> FlattenMethodCall(MethodCallExpression expression, List<Expression> expressions)
    {
        switch (expression.Method.Name)
        {
            case "Select":
                {
                    //The second argument will be the right side of the select statement e.g. property.Select(argument0 => argument1);
                    List<Expression> innerExpressions = Flatten(expression.Arguments[1], new List<Expression>());

                    //Create the select method.
                    //The first argument should always be the object we're passing in, so it will be the same.
                    //The second argument has been normailised into an object, e.g. from a single property or an anonyamous object containing multiple properties.
                    MethodInfo method = SelectMethod.MakeGenericMethod(expression.Method.GetGenericArguments().First(), typeof(object));

                    //Rebuild the select expression for each expression returned.
                    foreach (Expression innerExpression in innerExpressions)
                        expressions.Add(Expression.Call(method, expression.Arguments[0], innerExpression));

                    return expressions;
                }

            default: throw new ArgumentException("Invalid method call expression specified, the method call expression is to an unknown method.");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Flattens the new expression.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="expression">The expression.</param>
    /// <param name="expressions">The expressions.</param>
    /// <returns>List&lt;Expression&gt;.</returns>
    private List<Expression> FlattenNew(NewExpression expression, List<Expression> expressions)
    {
        //TODO: Make sure we're an anonyamous type.
        foreach (Expression argument in expression.Arguments)
            Flatten(argument, expressions);
        return expressions;
    }

}
```

The select method passed into the constructor is:

```
Enumerable.Select<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
```

I've written tests which check the following work as expected:

Single property:

Input:

```
book => book.CreatedBy
```

Output:

```
book => book.CreatedBy
```

Single property of a collection:

Input:

```
book => book.Publishers.Select(publisher => publisher.CreatedBy)
```

Output:

```
book => book.Publishers.Select(publisher => publisher.CreatedBy)
```

Multiple properties of a collection:

Input:

```
book => book.Publishers.Select(publisher => new
  {
    publisher.CreatedBy,
    publisher.DeletedBy
  });
```

Output:

```
book => book.Publishers.Select(publisher => publisher.CreatedBy);
book => book.Publishers.Select(publisher => publisher.DeletedBy);
```

I'll need to write more test but am happy I'm now on the right track.